# Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ vs Odroid C2 huge performance difference

Tags: performance, benchmarking

So i benchmarked my Raspi 3 B+ and an Odroid C2 with sysbench by in single and multithread operation by using

```
sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=20000 --num-threads=4 run
```

The results are kinda weird[image: Benchmark results]

So the Raspi seems to be like 14x slower than the Odroid C2 even though they share almost the same processor under the hood.

RAM shoudn't make the difference here.

Hope somebody got an idea how those results came together.

I installed sysbench via apt-get. OS on Raspi is Raspbian stretch. OS on Odroid is Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

simple... arm64 vs armhf.
RPi3B+ uses a 32bit OS and a 32bit version of sysbench.
ODROID C2 uses 64bit OS and 64bit version of sysbench.

That is what makes all the difference. The C2 is not really impressive performance wise.
Other "real world" application will still be faster on the C2 than on the RPi3B+ but the difference will be much much smaller.

There are even some 32bit boards that are far more powerful than the C2 that will have slower results with sysbench, but will outperform the C2 in nearly every other way.